# Skip excel macro in specific row according to one cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have an xlsm file which contains 2 sheets.
And a Macro code that makes a comparison between the two sheets, makes some changes, and creates a third new sheet as an output of the comparison.

```vba
         Option Explicit
          Option Compare Text
    Sub RNCAudit()
             Dim WS_Count As Integer
             Dim wsheet As Integer
             Dim RNC As String
             Dim object1 As String
             Dim object2 As String
             Dim object3 As String
             Dim object4 As String
             Dim object5 As String
             Dim object6 As String
             Dim j As Single
             Dim k As Integer
             Dim parameter As String
             Dim res As String
             Dim value As String
             Dim oldvalue As String
             k = 2
             Application.ScreenUpdating = False
             WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
             ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
             ActiveSheet.Move After:=Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
             ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(WS_Count + 1).Name = "Output"
             Worksheets(WS_Count + 1).Select
             Worksheets(WS_Count + 1).Cells(1, 1) = "Command"
             Worksheets(WS_Count + 1).Cells(1, 2) = "RNC"
             Worksheets(WS_Count + 1).Cells(1, 3) = "Object_2"
             Worksheets(WS_Count + 1).Cells(1, 4) = "Object_3"
             Worksheets(WS_Count + 1).Cells(1, 5) = "Object_4"
             Worksheets(WS_Count + 1).Cells(1, 6) = "Object_5"
             Worksheets(WS_Count + 1).Cells(1, 7) = "Object_6"
             Worksheets(WS_Count + 1).Cells(1, 8) = "Parameter_ID"
             Worksheets(WS_Count + 1).Cells(1, 9) = "Current_Setting"
             Worksheets(WS_Count + 1).Cells(1, 10) = "Target_Setting"
             
             For wsheet = 3 To WS_Count
             RNC = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(wsheet).Name
             
             j = 2
    
    While Worksheets("RNC_BaseLine").Cells(j, 1) <> ""
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        parameter = Trim(Worksheets("RNC_BaseLine").Cells(j, 1))
        object1 = Trim(Worksheets("RNC_BaseLine").Cells(j, 2))
        object2 = Trim(Worksheets("RNC_BaseLine").Cells(j, 3))
        object3 = Trim(Worksheets("RNC_BaseLine").Cells(j, 4))
        object4 = Trim(Worksheets("RNC_BaseLine").Cells(j, 5))
        object5 = Trim(Worksheets("RNC_BaseLine").Cells(j, 6))
        object6 = Trim(Worksheets("RNC_BaseLine").Cells(j, 7))
        value = Find_Value(wsheet, WS_Count, object1, object2, object3, object4, object5, object6, parameter)
        oldvalue = Worksheets("RNC_BaseLine").Cells(j, 8)
        If oldvalue <> value Then
            Worksheets("Output").Cells(k, 1) = "Set " & object1
            Worksheets("Output").Cells(k, 2) = RNC
            Worksheets("Output").Cells(k, 3) = object2
            Worksheets("Output").Cells(k, 4) = object3
            Worksheets("Output").Cells(k, 5) = object4
            Worksheets("Output").Cells(k, 6) = object5
            Worksheets("Output").Cells(k, 7) = object6
            Worksheets("Output").Cells(k, 8) = parameter
            Worksheets("Output").Cells(k, 9) = value
            Worksheets("Output").Cells(k, 10) = Worksheets("RNC_BaseLine").Cells(j, 8)
            
            k = k + 1
        End If
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        j = j + 1
    Wend
    
    Next
    
    MsgBox "Done at " & Time
    
    End Sub
```

Here is the Code that makes the comparison

```vba
    Private Function Find_Value(ByVal wsheet As Integer, ByVal WS_Count As Integer, _
      ByVal object1 As String, ByVal object2 As String, ByVal object3 As String, _
      ByVal object4 As String, ByVal object5 As String, ByVal object6 As String, _
      ByVal parameter As String) As String
    
    Dim i As Single
    Dim j As Single
    Dim encontrado As Boolean
    Dim encontrado2 As Boolean
    Dim SRH As Boolean
    Dim j2 As Single
    Dim j3 As Single
    Dim j4 As Single
    Dim j5 As Single
    Dim j6 As Single
    Dim FindString As String
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Rng2 As String
    Dim coma_pos As Integer
    Dim coma_pos_1 As Integer
    Dim coma_pos_2 As Integer
    Dim coma_pos_3 As Integer
    Dim colparam As Integer
    Dim find_type As Integer
    Dim valor As String
    encontrado = False
    encontrado2 = False
    SRH = False
    i = 2
    
    find_type = 1
    If Len(Trim(object2)) > 0 Then
        find_type = find_type + 1
    End If
    If Len(Trim(object3)) > 0 Then
        find_type = find_type + 1
    End If
    If Len(Trim(object4)) > 0 Then
        find_type = find_type + 1
    End If
    If Len(Trim(object5)) > 0 Then
        find_type = find_type + 1
    End If
    If Len(Trim(object6)) > 0 Then
        find_type = find_type + 1
    End If
    
    With Worksheets(wsheet).Range("A:A")
                  Set Rng = .Find(What:=object1, _
                                After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                MatchCase:=False)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                Application.Goto Rng, True
    End If
    End With
        While ((encontrado = False) And (encontrado2 = False))
                
                If SRH = True Then
                           
            With Worksheets(wsheet).Range(Selection.Offset(1, 0), Selection.End(xlDown))
                Set Rng = .Find(What:=object1, _
                                After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                MatchCase:=False)
            End With
            End If
            
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                Application.Goto Rng, True
            
            
                Select Case find_type
                Case 1
                            If InStr(Rng, parameter) > 0 Then
                               encontrado = True
                               valor = Mid(Rng, InStr(Rng, parameter) + Len(parameter) + 1, 200)
                               Else
                               encontrado = False
                               SRH = True
                            End If
                 Case 2
                        
                            If (InStr(Rng, parameter) > 0) Then
                                If (InStr(Rng, object2) > 0) Then
                                encontrado = True
                                valor = Mid(Rng, InStr(Rng, parameter) + Len(parameter) + 1, 200)
                                Else
                                encontrado = False
                                SRH = True
                                End If
                            Else
                            encontrado = False
                            SRH = True
                            End If
                  Case 3
                        
                            If (InStr(Rng, parameter) > 0) Then
                                If (InStr(Rng, object2) > 0) Then
                                    If (InStr(Rng, object3) > 0) Then
                                    encontrado = True
                                    valor = Mid(Rng, InStr(Rng, parameter) + Len(parameter) + 1, 200)
                                    Else
                                    encontrado = False
                                    SRH = True
                                    End If
                                    Else
                                    encontrado = False
                                    SRH = True
                                    End If
                             
                            Else
                            encontrado = False
                            SRH = True
                            End If
                   Case 4
                        
                            If (InStr(Rng, parameter) > 0) Then
                                If (InStr(Rng, object2) > 0) Then
                                    If (InStr(Rng, object3) > 0) Then
                                        If (InStr(Rng, object4) > 0) Then
                                        encontrado = True
                                        valor = Mid(Rng, InStr(Rng, parameter) + Len(parameter) + 1, 200)
                                        Else
                                        encontrado = False
                                        SRH = True
                                        End If
                                         Else
                                         encontrado = False
                                         SRH = True
                                        End If
                                         Else
                                encontrado = False
                                SRH = True
                                End If
                            Else
                            encontrado = False
                            SRH = True
                            End If
                  Case 5
                        
                            If (InStr(Rng, parameter) > 0) Then
                                If (InStr(Rng, object2) > 0) Then
                                    If (InStr(Rng, object3) > 0) Then
                                        If (InStr(Rng, object4) > 0) Then
                                            If (InStr(Rng, object5) > 0) Then
                                            encontrado = True
                                            valor = Mid(Rng, InStr(Rng, parameter) + Len(parameter) + 1, 200)
                                             Else
                                encontrado = False
                                SRH = True
                                            End If
                                             Else
                                encontrado = False
                                SRH = True
                                        End If
                                         Else
                                encontrado = False
                                SRH = True
                                    End If
                                     Else
                                encontrado = False
                                SRH = True
                                End If
                            Else
                            encontrado = False
                            SRH = True
                            End If
                  Case 6
                        
                            If (InStr(Rng, parameter) > 0) Then
                                If (InStr(Rng, object2) > 0) Then
                                    If (InStr(Rng, object3) > 0) Then
                                        If (InStr(Rng, object4) > 0) Then
                                            If (InStr(Rng, object5) > 0) Then
                                                If (InStr(Rng, object6) > 0) Then
                                                encontrado = True
                                                valor = Mid(Rng, InStr(Rng, parameter) + Len(parameter) + 1, 200)
                                                 Else
                                encontrado = False
                                SRH = True
                                                End If
                                                 Else
                                encontrado = False
                                SRH = True
                                            End If
                                             Else
                                encontrado = False
                                SRH = True
                                        End If
                                         Else
                                encontrado = False
                                SRH = True
                                    End If
                                     Else
                                encontrado = False
                                SRH = True
                                End If
                            Else
                            encontrado = False
                            SRH = True
                            End If
        End Select
        Else
        encontrado2 = True
        End If
        Wend
        'Else
        'End If
        'End If
        'End With
        
        'Wend
     
              
    
    If encontrado = True Then
        coma_pos_1 = InStr(valor, ",")
        coma_pos_2 = InStr(valor, "&")
        coma_pos_3 = InStr(valor, ";")
        
        If coma_pos_1 > 0 Then
         coma_pos = coma_pos_1
         If coma_pos_2 > 0 Then
         If coma_pos_2 < coma_pos_1 Then
         coma_pos = coma_pos_2
         End If
         End If
         If coma_pos_3 > 0 Then
         If coma_pos_3 < coma_pos Then
         coma_pos = coma_pos_3
         End If
         End If
         Else
         If coma_pos_2 > 0 Then
         coma_pos = coma_pos_2
         If coma_pos_3 > 0 Then
         If coma_pos_3 < coma_pos Then
         coma_pos = coma_pos_3
         End If
         End If
         Else
         If coma_pos_3 > 0 Then
         coma_pos = coma_pos_3
         End If
         End If
         End If
            Find_Value = Left(valor, coma_pos - 1)
    
        
    Else
        Find_Value = "NOT_FOUND"
    End If
    If encontrado2 = True Then
    Find_Value = "NOT_FOUND"
    End If
    'End If
    
     'End With
    On Error Resume Next
    
    'End With
    End Function
```

What I need to do is the following:-

I have added a new column (CAT) to the first sheet, this column's cells either empty or has a value of (ignore).

I need my code to check on that cell before the comparison and skip the comparison of the whole row if the (CAT) cell is equal to "ignore".

I hope That was clear enough

Thank you in advance

Comment: I suggest you to be more specific. I need my code to do something is vague. Where, what line, provide some sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to add a couple of lines something like this:

```vba
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("RNC_BaseLine")
'...
'...
While ws.Cells(j, 1) <> ""
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        'adjust "10" to the position of your column
        If ws.Cells(j, 10).Value <> "ignore" Then
    
            'do the rest of the checks

        End If 'not "ignore"

'...
'...
```

Comment: I start counting the columns starting from 0 .. is that right?

Comment: Columns start at 1.  A=1, E=5, J=10 etc